# Internet Explorer ignores Hashtag in URL

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, url-rewriting, iis-7.5, hashtag

I've got the following URL Rewrite Rules set up:

```
<rules>
            <rule name="Clean URL" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([A-Za-z0-9]+)([\?A-Za-z0-9#=&amp;]+)?$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx{R:2}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="CleanTest" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([a-z0-9/]+).aspx([a-zA-Z0-9\?#=&amp;]+)?$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}{R:2}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
```

What this does is show a clean (non-.aspx) URL in the client's address bar and additionally redirects every clean URL call to the corresponding .aspx-Page. This "generally" works fine. However, when my URL includes a hashtag, i.e. `Administration.aspx#first` the hashtag is missing after the redirection in IE only, it works perfectly fine in FF/Chrome, what could cause this?

Result after clicking on the Link in Chrome/FF:

`Administration#first`

Result in IE (9):

`Administration`

Addendum: It works perfectly fine for GET-Parameters.

Link: `Login.aspx?logout=1`

IE: `Login?logout=1`

FF/Chrome: `Login?logout=1`

Answer (score 2):

As the hashtag is mainly is for the browser on the client side to know where to scroll within a page, it seems logical to me that not all browsers send it to the server. However I am not sure what the specification says about it.